# JDBC Performance - passing large resultset from database to Java

Tags: java, oracle

I have a performance related question. I need to retrieve about 500 rows from the database for the purpose of using the Apache POI to export the results into a Microsoft Excel spreadsheet.

Up until now for all my database queries I have been populating a PL/SQL object in the database layer and then returning that PL/SQL object to the Java and looping through the results.

But now that I need to return such a large result set to the Java from the db layer I've been asked a question about whether or not I think it might be better performance wise to return the 500 rows into the Java via an XML Clob.

This is a bit of an open question but I was hoping to get peoples opinion on this please.

thanks

Comment: 500 rows is not large, unless each row is huge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/resltset.htm#JJDBC28621

> By default, when Oracle JDBC runs a query, it retrieves a result set
>   of 10 rows at a time from the database cursor. This is the default
>   Oracle row fetch size value. You can change the number of rows
>   retrieved with each trip to the database cursor by changing the row
>   fetch size value.

The following methods are available in all Statement, PreparedStatement, CallableStatement, and ResultSet objects for setting and getting the fetch size:

```
void setFetchSize(int rows) throws SQLException
int getFetchSize() throws SQLException
```

Comment: +1 This is in general the correct answer - though it is true that 500 rows is not large.

Comment: Once again emphasizing that 500 rows is not large, I would suggest setting the fetch size to match the number of rows you expect to retrieve to limit the roundtrips to the database. YMMV, but my experience is that the optimal fetch size is often somewhere between 500 and 1000 rows.

Comment: @BrettOkken Do you have any idea what the data size of optimal fetch size would be?  Obviously row sizes may vary considerably.

Comment: @ScaryWombat It is something to test on a per table basis. Obviously things like blobs or clubs or UDT columns can impact this. I am simply stating that most tables I have done this type of testing with, I have landed on a fetch size of 500 - 1000 in an attempt to maximize overall throughput.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Java ResultSet. This will fetch only some rows at a time, as you need them. Here is an example of how to use it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html
Basically, every time you ask for a new row, as in rs.next(), the JDBC system decides if the data is available on the client, or needs to be fetched from the server. This way, you are not fetching all of the data at once.

Comment: @ScaryWombat *May* result in a call to the DB. What really happens is that *N* rows are returned at a time, where *N* is under your control via `Statement.setFetchSize().`